# Mysql Transaction (Mysql)

Tags: c#, mysql, insert

tengo un inquietud como puedo mejorar esta consulta. Pues estoy aprendiendo a usar Transaction. una de mis dudas es como puedo usar el rollback on error

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_insert_transaction(
IN _id_usuario INT,
IN _id_proveedor INT,
IN _fecha_ingreso INT)
BEGIN
SET
    AUTOCOMMIT = 0 ;
START TRANSACTION
    ;
INSERT INTO tb_ingreso(
    id_usuario,
    id_proveedor,
    fecha_ingreso
)
VALUES(
_id_usuario,
_id_proveedor,
_fecha_ingreso
) ;
SELECT
LAST_INSERT_ID() ;
   COMMIT;
END $$
DELIMITER
;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar un try/catch y cuando suceda algún error mandes llamar el rollback. También añado una consulta para obtener el error

```
BEGIN TRY  
    --consulta con error
END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    SELECT   
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
        ,ERROR_SEVERITY() AS ErrorSeverity  
        ,ERROR_STATE() AS ErrorState  
        ,ERROR_PROCEDURE() AS ErrorProcedure  
        ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine  
        ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  

    IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0  
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;  
END CATCH;
```

Comment: En el caso del consulta con error como seria un ejemplo que no entiendo muy bien esa parte

Comment: Imagina que dentro del BEGIN TRY tienes 3 insert y despues tienes un query que genera un error. Ejemplo: SELECT 1/0;  el try al detectar el error te enviaria al BEGIN CATCH y en el select debe de mostrarte cual fue el error, la linea en la que sucedio ese error, el numero de error y la severidad del error. Al final genera el rollback para que los inserts no se lleven acabo